# In matlab, find the frequency at which unique rows appear in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In Matlab, say I have the following matrix, which represents a population of 10 individuals:

```
pop = [0 0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 0 0; 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0];
```

Where rows of `ones` and `zeros` define 6 different 'types' of individuals.

```
a = [0 0 0 0 0];
b = [1 0 0 0 0];
c = [1 1 0 0 0];
d = [1 1 1 0 0];
e = [1 1 1 1 0];
f = [1 1 1 1 1];
```

I want to define the proportion/frequency of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` in `pop`.

I want to end up with the following list:

```
a = 0.5;
b = 0.1;
c = 0;
d = 0.2;
e = 0;
f = 0.2;
```

One way I can think of is by summing the rows, then counting the number of times each appears, and then sorting and indexing

```
sum_pop = sum(pop')';
x = unique(sum_pop);
N = numel(x);
count = zeros(N,1);
   for l = 1:N
      count(l) = sum(sum_pop==x(l));
   end
pop_frequency = [x(:) count/10];
```

But this doesn't quite get me what I want (i.e. when frequency = 0) and it seems there must be a faster way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics Toolbox) to get all frequencies:

```
indiv = [a;b;c;d;e;f]; %// matrix with all individuals
result = mean(pdist2(pop, indiv)==0, 1);
```

This gives, in your example,

```
result =
    0.5000    0.1000         0    0.2000         0    0.2000
```

Equivalently, you can use `bsxfun` to manually compute `pdist2(pop, indiv)==0`, as in [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532801/2586922).

---

For the specific individuals in your example (that can be identified by the number of ones) you could also do

```
result = histc(sum(pop, 2), 0:size(pop,2)) / size(pop,1);
```

Comment: I like the `histc` one for its optimal complexity!

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**

With `bsxfun` -

```
A = cat(1,a,b,c,d,e,f)
out = squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,pop,permute(A,[3 2 1])),2),1))/size(pop,1)
```

Output -

```
out =
    0.5000
    0.1000
         0
    0.2000
         0
    0.2000
```

---

**Approach #2**

If those elements are binary numbers, you can convert them into `decimal` format.

Thus, decimal format for `pop` becomes -

```
>> bi2de(pop)
ans =
     0
     7
    31
     7
     0
     0
     1
    31
     0
     0
```

And that of the concatenated array, A becomes -

```
>> bi2de(A)
ans =
     0
     1
     3
     7
    15
    31
```

Finally, you need to count the decimal formatted numbers from `A` in that of `pop`, which you can do with `histc`. Here's the code -

```
A = cat(1,a,b,c,d,e,f)
out = histc(bi2de(pop),bi2de(A))/size(pop,1)
```

Output -

```
out =
    0.5000
    0.1000
         0
    0.2000
         0
    0.2000
```

Comment: I was expecting this answer (second part) :-) I tried to be quicker!

Comment: @LuisMendo Well yeah too predictable :)

Comment: @Divakar great, then I can remove my answer. Thanks for doing a working example. Imo, the solution with unique should be used in case you share code with others, or share licenses with others. However, unique is not the fastest functions, so in case of performance problem, I guess readability need to stand back in favor of performance. Then code with equivalent output can be added as a comment or in documentation.

Comment: @patrik Ah I was about to remove my second approach after seeing your edits just now! I would not mind removing should you consider undeleting yours!

Comment: @patrik I would think `unique` to be quite fast for this problem, but again we are dealing with `'rows'` option, so I am not too sure on that.

Comment: I like the `histc` one for it's low complexity!

Comment: @knedlsepp yup, should be quite efficient that one!

Answer (score 4):

There is some functionality in unique that can be used for this. If

```
[q,w,e] = unique(pop,'rows');
```

`q` is the matrix of unique rows, `w` is the index of the row first appears in the matrix. The third element `e` contains indices of `q` so that `pop = q(e,:)`. Armed with this, the rest of the problem should be straight forward. The probability of a value in `e` should be the probability that this row appears in `pop`.

The counting can be done with `histc`

```
histc(e,1:max(e))/length(e)
```

and the non occuring rows can be found with

```
ismember(a,q,'rows')
```

There is of course other ways as well, maybe (probably) faster ways, or oneliners. Why I post this is because it provides a way that is easy to understand, readable and that does not require any special toolboxes.

**EDIT**
This example gives expected output

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;1,1,0,0,0;1,1,1,0,0;1,1,1,1,0;1,1,1,1,1]; % catenated a-f
[q,w,e] = unique(pop,'rows');
prob = histc(e,1:max(e))/length(e);
out = zeros(size(a,1),1);
out(ismember(a,q,'rows')) = prob;
```

Comment: This is great, as it works in a more general situation and is of optimal complexity!

Answer (score 4):

I think `ismember` is the most direct and general way to do this. If your groups were more complicated, this would be the way to go:

```
population = [0,0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,0,0; 1,1,1,1,1; 1,1,1,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0; 1,0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,1,1; 0,0,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0,0];
groups = [0,0,0,0,0; 1,0,0,0,0; 1,1,0,0,0; 1,1,1,0,0; 1,1,1,1,0; 1,1,1,1,1];

[~, whichGroup] = ismember(population, groups, 'rows');
freqOfGroup = accumarray(whichGroup, 1)/size(groups, 1);
```

In your special case the groups can be represented by their sums, so if this generic solution is not fast enough, use the `sum`-`histc` simplification [*Luis* used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532885/3139711).